# click button on modal ViewController then go to new page swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

My case is I wanna show new page from `ViewController` modal when click button, can we do this like android just `onClick` on the button and change the page ?

[image]

> Click from MainViewController > present modally > ProfileViewController
>   Then ProfileViewController > AboutViewController (dismissed)

In My `ProfileViewController`

```
@IBAction func testSupport(_ sender: Any) {
    let aboutView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutView, animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You don't want to push a `UIViewController`, you want to present it modally.

Comment: no, i dont. so the flow is i want to tap button from mainView(profile icon) to present profileView modally, then from modal profileView i have button(support) , i wanna tap this buttonSupport then go to AboutView, Dont back to main when click support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this :

- Using Storyboard.

Just Ctrl-drag from your ViewController to the
   AboutViewController you want. Then a popup will appear where
   you can choose which segue you want to perform (modal)

Now click on the segue (the link created between the 2 ViewControllers, and give it an identifier).

Add this code in your ViewController (the one you are currently in)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueId" {
         let aboutViewController = segue.destination as! AboutViewController
         // do some init if you want
    }
}
```

Perform the segue within you button action :

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueId", sender: self)
}
```

- Programmatically.

You can present the ViewController just like your are currently doing, but you are asking for a modal presentation so :

```
 @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {

     let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let aboutViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController

     self.present(aboutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) nil)
}
```

Comment: it's work well with the last code, thanks dude.
so if i want to go back to the main(map) with the button, i just code it to self.dismiss right ?

Comment: Exactly. You can also implement a tap outside to dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates for this. In your `ProfileViewController.swift` declare a protocol

```
protocol ProfileViewControllerDelegate {
    func didPressSupportButton()
}
```

Then in your `ProfileViewController` class declare

```
var delegate: ProfileViewControllerDelegate?
```

In your support action:

```
@IBAction func testSupport(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didPressSupportButton()
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

When you present your view, if you're doing it programmatically, or in prepare for segue:

```
yourModalViewController.delegate = self
```

Then in your `MainViewController` conform to protocol

```
extension MainViewController: ProfileViewControllerDelegate {
    func didPressSupportButton {
        let aboutView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutView, animated: true)
     }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm gonna try it later :)

Answer (score 1):

Your "self" is presented. It have not navigationcontroller so you can pushviewcontroller.
Try:

```
@IBAction func testSupport(_ sender: Any) {
    let aboutView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            topController.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutView, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the first code for navigate to the About page right ?
and the second code to go back from About page to map ?